# -Wunused-variable compiler says ERROR

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Recently I'm starting to program in C + + (I come from Java, and it costs me a little change haha). Under Windows everything right. The problem is that I switched to Linux and this is where I have problems with the compiler. It is usually when you declare a variable and is not used, the compiler displays a "warning" saying that the variable is not used, but I (under linuxmint 15) throws me as "error" and leaves no compile: C. I do not know if anyone has this happened, but I'm sick at the time of making large programs (more than one class).

a little example:
[image]

Comment: Show your compilation command (the compiler is `g++`). Does it has `-Werror`? (you surely want `-Wall` at least); your picture show some IDE, not the compiler (which is always a command line).

Comment: yes i'm using code::blocks 
there is a capture of compilation
[img](http://imageshack.com/scaled/large/585/8gl8.png)

Comment: That is not a compiler, but an IDE. You should compile on the command line (and later, configure your IDE so that it runs the wanted commands). And your picture shows a warning. It is the IDE which handles it as some error apparently (perhaps because of the Spanish language setting?). Try to compile in a terminal on a command line (with a command starting with `g++ -Wall`, or perhaps using  `make`)

Comment: there is a [screenshoot](http://imageshack.com/a/img812/4470/a3m2.png). on commandline has no error then i guess the problem is the IDE (?).
I need to change any setting for SP lang? :O

Comment: Or take the good habit to compile on the command line. Did you consider `emacs`? BTW, please if possible put paragraphs with your code and commands in your questions (not as links to something elsewhere)! Learn how to format questions and answers properly on StackOverflow! BTW *IDE* means [Integrated Development Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)

Comment: LOL- i changed system language to english and it works haha thx!!!

Comment: Oh, I should have linked you this in the first place: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,9489.msg67120.html

Answer (score 2):

The unusued variable warning is the result of invoking GCC with either

```
g++ -Wunused-variable ...
```

If this is the case, don't specify that argument. Or it's because of -Wall:

```
g++ -Wall ...
```

In which case, specify -Wno-unused-variable

It's being thrown as an error because you have the '-Werror' argument too.

There are a few reasons for this warning: It is possible to "shadow" variables between scopes in C++ and so a common cause of unused variables is when you have two variables of the same name.

```
int i = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { // << this is SECOND variable called i that hides the previous
}
if (day == "Monday") {
    int i; // << you can't see the second i here, this is a third that also hides the first.
    ...
}
// std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl; // we can see original i again here
```

There are *two* variables called "i" here. If you uncommented the last line, it would print 5, unrelated to the two *additional* variables called 'i'.

Without the std::cout, though, the original, outer, i is never used. Perhaps that last "int i" is an error.

Another common problem relates to the ability to have global variables in C++

```
int Whoops; // GLOBAL: NEVER EVER TOUCH THIS.

int func() {
    int whoops; // LOCAL: ALWAYS TOUCH THIS.
    Whoops = 42; // >W<hoops!
}
```

You would receive a warning that "whoops" was an unused variable to aide in detecting you had modified the wrong variable.

Comment: I understand, but on windows when i have an unused variable, the compiler says "warning", and compiles anyway. but on Linux says "Error"
Windows:
**0 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)**
Linux:
**1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)**

Comment: Because you're compiling with -Werror because whatever checkbox codeblocks has for 'treat warnings as errors' is checked.

Comment: No, `g++` is giving you a *warning* (unless you pass it `-Werror`). It is your IDE which is mistaken. So avoid using it. And at least for stack overflow, don't configure your system with Spanish. Use `LANG=C LC_ALL=C` in your shell environment.